# Automatically rotate image when is width bigger than height in PHP

Tags: php, css, image, image-rotation, autorotate

I asked in past, but I am not sure we understand & I still havent solution.
I need elegant solution when;
I have photo 600x800 & I need show it on my site rotated on 90 degrees, so result will be, when I print php page all photos will be verticaly automaticly.

e.g.
I have a lot of photos, two kinds: 800x600 & 600x800.
I need on my php page showed all of them 800x600 in original and all 600x800 rotated on 90 degrees.

I need some really simple solution, I am out of mind totally. Some function which can rotate images which have bigger width than height.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you have 2 of each image; 800x600 and 600x800?
What is your current output? Could you post your php logic?

Comment: You can rotate your images either on the server using GD or ImageMagick, or in the browser using CSS transforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using PHP function `getimagesize()` you can get `width` and `height` of your image:

```
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageUrl);
```

Then, in your template:

```
  <?php if($width > $height): ?>
        //put css here as you want
  <?php else: ?>
        //put css here as you want
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) for detect image width and if width is 800px add inline css like this

```
style="-moz-transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); -o-transform: rotate(90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); transform: rotate(90deg);"
```

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize() function will give you width and height and by using [imagerotate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) you can rotate that image to any desired angle.

Try this:-

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'php.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
?>
```

Comment: This isnt correct form: ---  echo('<img src="'.$photo1.'" imagerotate(90) />');  ---? :/ isnt work